# libreadline is not exiting on Ctrl+C from paginated "__more__" output state (possible completions on tab)

Tags: sigint, libreadline

My application uses libreadline to auto complete timezone strings (on pressing tab) for `timezone` command.
As there are lot of possible completions the output is paginated with `__more__`.
In this state if I press `q` it exits fine but if I press `Ctrl+C` the behavior is as shown below.. (it wont exit until all the entries in the buffer printed out, but printing junk).

```
$ timezone <tab>
Display all 200 possibilities? (y or n) y    
Africa/Maputo                   America/Moncton                 Asia/Kuwait                     Europe/Stockholm
Africa/Maseru                   America/Monterrey               Asia/Macau                      Europe/Tallinn
Africa/Mbabane                  America/Montevideo              Asia/Magadan                    Europe/Tirane
Africa/Mogadishu                America/Montreal                Asia/Makassar                   Europe/Uzhgorod
Africa/Monrovia                 America/Montserrat              Asia/Manila                     Europe/Vaduz
--More--^C
�"^TxU                         ^P�"^TxU                        ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU
^P^?"^TxU                       ^P�"^TxU                        ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU
0�"^TxU                         ^P�"^TxU                        ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU
0�"^TxU                         ^P�"^TxU                        ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU
0�"^TxU                         ^P�"^TxU                        ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU
0�"^TxU                         ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU                         ^P�"^TxU
0�"^TxU                         ��"^TxU                         ��"^TxU                         @�"^TxU
```

By the way my `SIGINT` handler function is as below, and I am using `rl_attempted_completion_function` to register my own function to provide possible completion strings `char**`.

```
rl_initialize();
printf("\n");
rl_forced_update_display();
```

How to make `Ctrl+C` to behave exactly as pressing `q` on pagination?.

Comment: If I am right, libreadline is using `popen` for pagination, so I may need an api to close that.